# Trying to edit History or Drafts list when Delete action is visible does nothing

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to the "History" or "Drafts" section of the app.
2. Swipe one of the rows in the table to reveal the "Delete" `UITableViewRowAction`.
3. Press the edit button.

Expected behavior:

The table view enters the edit state.

Actual behavior:

Nothing happens.

Additional notes:
I know this is annoying, but you may want to keep track of the current cell that has the `UITableViewRowAction` visible in order to reset the table view state.  Or reload the row.

> [image: Bug]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)